# Making two line navigation with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'am trying to do two line bootstrap navigation like on picture. How could I achieve that? As you see the top and botton navs are inline verticaly with each other.

The idea is that if page width comes to small tablet size or mobile size the hole navigation is on one dropdown list button, like on basic bootstrap navbar.

Any other idea of making same sort of navigation as simple as possible?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tryed bacis bootstrap navbars, basic button pils, but non of them is not working like i would like it to work. Main problem is that buttons are inline verticaly.

Comment: Ensure you've included Bootstrap files(css/js) on the page; Then go to Bootstrap site and copy the markup of its `nav` using Developer Console of your browser (or by doing 'View Source'). Play around with this until you get what you desire.

Comment: Now I have two lines of navbars. Is there some trick I could use to make LI tags go vertically even or Do I have to hard code those LI:s to look like that?  something like making every LI tag it's own width...

Comment: ..How to collapse two navs to one collapsed mobile nav? Is it possible with bootstrap?